# CodeIgniter form validation fails for hashed password data only

Tags: codeigniter

I am using *PHP 5.5.27* and *Codeigniter3* to developed my code.

I used `password_hash()` to encrypt my password and store it in database. Also password `varchar(255)` is column size.

When I entered plain (unhashed) password then codeigniter validation run properly. But If I used hashed password (in text format) then form validation fails. Also If I used wrong password then also it works properly.

How can I solve this problem and make it work for hashed password also?

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Sorry,but I can't. I am using multiple databases in this project. As it's Software as service type of project.